# Set my home screen as default programmatically

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen, native-activity

Assume that I have multiple home screen installed in my android device.
When booting or pressing the HOME key, a dialog is shown to the user to select desired HOME screen and a check box to set this action as default.

I would like to know the code where the "default" home screen would be set when I select the "set this action as default" checkbox and launch the application.

I need this to programatically control the home screen in two different modes.

Regards,
Praga

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't for security purposes. (i.e. if I can programmatically set myself as the default home screen, then I can theoretically "lock" the user out of their own device)

If you actually want to implement this you are going to have to build your own version of the OS and install it on your own devices and then you can getting working within your OS, but not for people who have the stock OS builds.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to achieve this by modifying the source code and make my own ROM. I just want to know, what change need to be done in the Android source code to achieve this. I am trying to find the point where the home screen is launched when the device is booting.